# How can I pass modelformset_factory validation in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have 2 two models with a one-to-one relation as follow.

```
class Kategori(models.Model):
    urun = models.CharField(db_column='Urun', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    kategori = models.CharField(db_column='Kategori', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ust_kategori = models.CharField(db_column='Ust_Kategori', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    urun_adi = models.CharField(db_column='URUN_ADI', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ur_id = models.CharField(db_column='UR_ID', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    marka = models.CharField(db_column='MARKA', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cesidi = models.CharField(db_column='CESIDI', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    miktar = models.FloatField(db_column='MIKTAR', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    birim = models.CharField(db_column='BIRIM', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    adet = models.FloatField(db_column='ADET', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class categoryprob(models.Model):
    urun = models.OneToOneField(Kategori,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="prob")
    kategori = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ust_kategori = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    urun_adi = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    marka = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cesidi = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    miktar = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    birim = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    adet = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

I am trying to update `Kategori` model objects depend on `categoryprob` inputs. I prepare a form to get `Kategori` objects depend on their probability at `categoryprob` as follows.

```
from django import forms
from mailservice.models import categoryprob,Kategori 

PASS_PROB = 0.8

class predictionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Kategori
        fields = ["urun","kategori","ust_kategori","urun_adi","marka","cesidi","miktar","birim","adet"]
        
        widgets = {
            'kategori': forms.Select(choices=set(Kategori.objects.all().values_list('kategori','kategori'))),
            'ust_kategori': forms.Select(choices=set(Kategori.objects.all().values_list('ust_kategori','ust_kategori'))),
            'marka': forms.Select(choices=set(Kategori.objects.all().values_list('marka','marka'))),
            'cesidi': forms.Select(choices=set(Kategori.objects.all().values_list('cesidi','cesidi'))),
            'miktar': forms.Select(choices=set(Kategori.objects.all().values_list('miktar','miktar'))),
            'birim': forms.Select(choices=set(Kategori.objects.all().values_list('birim','birim'))),
            'adet': forms.Select(choices=set(Kategori.objects.all().values_list('adet','adet'))),
        }
        
        labels ={
            'urun':""
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(predictionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        prob = categoryprob.objects.get(urun=instance)

        self.fields['urun'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

        if float(prob.kategori) > PASS_PROB:
            self.fields['kategori'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
            self.fields['kategori'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:red'
        else:
            self.fields['kategori'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:green'

        if float(prob.ust_kategori) > PASS_PROB:
            self.fields['ust_kategori'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
            self.fields['ust_kategori'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:red'
        else:
            self.fields['ust_kategori'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:green'
        
        if float(prob.urun_adi) > PASS_PROB:
            self.fields['urun_adi'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
            self.fields['urun_adi'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:red'
        else:
            self.fields['urun_adi'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:green'
        
        if float(prob.marka) > PASS_PROB:
            self.fields['marka'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
            self.fields['marka'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:red'
        else:
            self.fields['marka'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:green'
        
        if float(prob.cesidi) > PASS_PROB:
            self.fields['cesidi'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
            self.fields['cesidi'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:red'
        else:
            self.fields['cesidi'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:green'

        if float(prob.miktar) > PASS_PROB:
            self.fields['miktar'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
            self.fields['miktar'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:red'
        else:
            self.fields['miktar'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:green'
        
        if float(prob.birim) > PASS_PROB:
            self.fields['birim'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
            self.fields['birim'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:red'
        else:
            self.fields['birim'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:green'
        
        if float(prob.adet) > PASS_PROB:
            self.fields['adet'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
            self.fields['adet'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:red'
        else:
            self.fields['adet'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:green'
```

I use `modelformset_factory` to render 3 of them together. Everything works fine when I am rending on the template as follows.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    <div class="form-row">
        {{ p_form.management_form }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        {%for form in p_form%}
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    {{form.urun|as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    
                    <div class="row">   
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col ">
                            {{form.kategori|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.ust_kategori|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.urun_adi|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.marka|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.cesidi|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.miktar|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.birim|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.adet|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Kaydet</button>
</form>
```

When I submit with post method as follows:

```
def editCategories(request):
    categories = Kategori.objects.all().order_by('?')[:3]
    CategoryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Kategori, form = predictionForm,extra=0)
    formset = CategoryFormSet(queryset = categories)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
        return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
    content = {
        "p_form":formset,
    }  
    
    return render(request,'edit_categories.html',content)
```

formset.is_valid return false all the time.

I couldn't figure out how to validate all forms at once. Do you have any suggestion?

Picture of template output:

[image]

The output of the request.POST:

```
<QueryDict: {'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['3'], 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': ['3'], 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['*****'], 'form-0-id': ['125'], 'form-0-urun': ['_MotorinEcoForce'], 'form-0-urun_adi': ['asdasd'], 'form-1-id': ['186'], 'form-1-urun': ['7 stick sakız karpuz aromalı 12 adet'], 'form-1-marka': ['7 days'], 'form-2-id': ['159'], 'form-2-urun': ['7 Days Kruvasan Kayısılı Tekli 72 g'], 'form-2-kategori': ['Sebze']}>
```

Comment: You haven't passed any data to your formset, how will it ever be valid?...

Comment: I am passing at editCategories view `CategoryFormSet(queryset = categories)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can say there are two kinds of forms a *bound* form and an *unbound* form. What is the difference between these? Well a bound form is passed some data `MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` and an unbound form isn't passed any data `MyForm()`. By logic an unbound form can never be valid because, well it was **never submitted** and it is assumed to be created to simply display / render the form.

This logic similarly follows for formsets, and hence as you haven't passed any data to your formset it will never be valid. Another thing to be considered is that you haven't rendered the *hidden* fields for the formset. A formset makes certain hidden fields so that it can recognize which sub form is for which objects and some other things like deletion, etc. Without these hidden fields also your formset would be invalid.

Hence your view should be like:

```
def editCategories(request):
    categories = Kategori.objects.all().order_by('?')[:3]
    CategoryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Kategori, form = predictionForm,extra=0)
    formset = CategoryFormSet(queryset = categories)

    if request.method == "POST":
        # Will get inefficient later on when you have many objects in the database, look for a different solution
        formset = CategoryFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES) # Make a bound formset in case of a POST request
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
        return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
    content = {
        "p_form":formset,
    }
    return render(request,'edit_categories.html',content)
```

Your template should be like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    <div class="form-row">
        {{ p_form.management_form }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        {%for form in p_form%}
            {# Render hidden fields #}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    {{form.urun|as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    
                    <div class="row">   
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col ">
                            {{form.kategori|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.ust_kategori|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.urun_adi|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.marka|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.cesidi|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.miktar|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.birim|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-md-3 col">
                            {{form.adet|as_crispy_field}}
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Kaydet</button>
</form>
```

Also you set fields to be disabled only by adding a disabled attribute to their widget, this means they are not posted with the form, but since the field *itself* is not disabled it looks for their data, doesn't find it and sets it to `None`, instead you want to disable the field itself:

```
class predictionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        # truncated for shortness
        # similar needs to be done for other fields too
        if float(prob.kategori) > PASS_PROB:
            self.fields['kategori'].disabled = True
            self.fields['kategori'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'border-color:red'
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it gives me another error `categoryprob matching query does not exist.`. When I print instance at `predictionForm`'s `__init__` , it prints like this`Kategori object (None)` then it gives the error. So during validation None object return to forms.

Comment: Yes I use exactly what you write

Comment: Yes, it is printing. I also add a screenshot of template and the print output to the question.

Comment: @MuratDemir wait you have this as your queryset `Kategori.objects.all().order_by('?')[:3]` the `.order_by('?')` means _random_ ordering, this means likely objects other than the ones passed as the queryset can be present in the POST data and hence you don't have matching data with the formset. Why exactly do you do this?

Comment: @MuratDemir try writing `formset = CategoryFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)` instead of `formset = CategoryFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset = categories)` in case of the POST request, this might work but it will cause all the instances of your model to be fetched from the database, you might need to make some adjustments to how you get the queryset if you want to make a formset for randomly ordered querysets.

Comment: Omg, wait it is validating and saving but now the problem here is when I edit 1 column it is deleting all other columns.

Comment: @MuratDemir that is likely because instead of disabling the field you are just adding a disabled attribute to its widget and hence it is not posted (which is fine) but the field then considers that it means to set the value to null. Instead of `self.fields['ust_kategori'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True`, etc. you want to be writing `self.fields['ust_kategori'].disabled = True`

Comment: Omg, you are a genius. Thank you so much It works perfectly. I finish my task finally you save my day.